# Accessing a vector from a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, vector

Am working in a project where i have to build a library and use that library in a main function.The Library is .dll and it has 7 headers and 5 source files.In a header i declared a vector and i implemented in one of the source files.Since i have to access this vector in my main program i declared it global in that source file and as extern in that header file.Now after i build my Dll and linked it with my main program i cannot able to access the vector as it is showing "Unresolved External".I don't know what exactly the mistake as it working perfectly for Load time Linking but getting Error during Run time Linking.Please any help is welcomed.My code is something like this

```
NTFS-STRUCT.h            ---- > Library Header

_cdecl(dllexports) extern std::vector<std::string>files;



NTFS-Search.cpp             ------ > Library Source file

#include "NTFS-STRUCT.h"

vector<string>files;         ---> Global Vector for accessing in Main program


MFT-List   --- > Main program

#include "NTFS-STRUCT.h"


cout << "Vector size" << files.size();
```

P.S Since i used Dll to link with main program also it has to be run time linking i set the configuration in VS2010(platform which am working) as Delay Dll.

Comment: When MFT-LIST.cpp reads NTFS-STRUCT.h, it must see dllimport, not dllexport. Use a macro to distinguish the "build dll" case from the "build exe" one.

Comment: @manuell i tried something like this in my header.               #ifdef NTFS_STRUCT
#define NTFS_STRUCT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define NTFS_STRUCT extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif                                                               Please help me by specyfing what i have to include in my NTFS-Search.cpp(Source) and MFT-LIST.cpp(Main program)

Comment: Note that sharing global variables between EXE and DLL is not best thing to do. You could have a DLL exported function taking a reference to a vector and updating it when called.

Comment: @manuell I tried a function returning vector inside a dll when it is called from main but ended up with Heap Corruption and became mad of finding where that problem occurred.

Comment: First verify my answer does solve your problem, and then, maybe, make a second try with a function taking a vector *reference* as parameter. Make sure that EXE and DLL are build with same settings (C RunTime, Debug/Release, etc.)

Comment: Did my answer fix your link problem?

Comment: @manuell The usage of ur macro statement in my program causes "Cannot delay load NTFS_SEARCH.dll due to import of data symbol _declspec(dllimport) vector....".If i tries with function taking vector as reference then i got error as "Corruption of Heap"...Please me how to alleviate this

Comment: I already commented: You can't use /DELAYLOAD if you export datas. See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w59k653y.aspx

Comment: @manuell I studied that reference and now in such a case how to link that .exp file which was created by the LINK in my project ?

Comment: The EXE must be linked with the LIB file, not the EXP file. What Development environment do you use? Is that Visual Studio? Which version?

Comment: @manuell Yup VisualStudio 2010. How to link with that LIB file then ?

Comment: :-) You will have a hard time doing c++ DLL devs, if you don't know how to link... See updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a macro to distinguish the "build dll" case from the "build exe" one.

DLL Header:

```
// NTFS-STRUCT.h
#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define DECLSPEC_DLL __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define DECLSPEC_DLL __declspec( dllimport )
#endif

DECLSPEC_DLL extern std::vector<std::string> files;
```

Dll implementation:

```
// NTFS-Search.cpp
#define BUILD_DLL
#include "NTFS-STRUCT.h"
std::vector<std::string> files;
```

EXE:

```
// MFT-List.cpp
#include "NTFS-STRUCT.h"

cout << "Vector size" << files.size();
```

EDIT: how to use an exported function taking a vector by reference:

```
DECLSPEC_DLL void UpdateVector( std::vector<std::string> & files );
```

If you experience heap corruption, that may be because you don't build the EXE and the DLL with the **same and good** options for the C RunTime library.
Options **must be** :
`Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)` or `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)`
Set theses options in `Property->C++->Code Generation`

EDIT2: how to link

Method one: use a #pragma directive in the DLL header.

```
#pragma lib( comment, "mylib.lib" )
```

Method two: use the dependencies settings.

1. Make the DLL project a dependency of the EXE in the "Project dependencies" for the solution
2. Set to `yes` the `Link Library dependencies` in the `Linker->General` properties for the EXE

Method three: explicitly add the library file (LIB)

Go to the `Linker->Input` properties and add the lib file to the `Additional Dependencies` list, for the EXE

Comment: Generally `BUILD_DLL ` it is added to the DLL-project build configuration for preprocessor macro definitions, but that hardly detracts from the validity that is this answer. +1.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. The BUILD_DLL #define in the source code, and only in the dll.cpp source code, seems more clear and easy to me.

Comment: @manuell btw what is that BUILD_DLL u put as #ifdef..whether i have to make any changes in project sttings or wat ? Thanks for the snippet but it is showing error.:(

Comment: @WarriorPrince BUILD_DLL is #define'd in NTFS-Search.cpp, before the #include. What error is showing?

Comment: @manuell its a weird error in the statement DECLSPEC_DLL extern std::vector<std::string> files; -- type specifier assumed default as int, vector is not a member of std,string is not a member of std

Comment: @WarriorPrince You have to #include <vector> and <string> somewhere, either in stdafx.h, or on top of current header. How did you deal with that in your version of NTFS-STRUCT.h?

Comment: @manuell ya now that error disappears and a link problem occurred "Cannot delay load NTFS_SEARCH.dll due to import of data symbol _declspec(dllimport) vector...."Please tell how to alleviate it ?

Comment: You can't use /DELAYLOAD if you export datas. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w59k653y.aspx That's another reason to switch to an exported function taking the vector ref as argument.

Comment: @manuell Oh!! thanks a lot....I changed the code generation thing which really helps now and i made changes like not using delay dll.i just include the path where the .dll lies and it links automatically with import library.Thanks a lot again :)